# lmfit model for multi exponential decay

Tags: python-3.x, math, physics, curve-fitting, lmfit

I am trying to perform a fitting for my data using the **lmfit package**. However I couldnt find any built-in model for a multi-exponential decay. I have tried to create my own function, and then to fit it.
My code is the following:

```
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import lmfit
from lmfit.models import ExponentialModel, LinearModel
from lmfit import Model, Parameter, report_fit

def MultiExpDecay(tiempo,C1,tau1,C2,tau2):
    return C1*np.exp(-tiempo/tau1)+C2*np.exp(-tiempo/tau2)

def MultiExpDecay_fit():
    C1s = []
    C1s_error = []
    C2s = []
    C2s_error = []
    tau1s = []
    tau1s_error = []
    tau2s = []
    tau2s_error = []
    Fit_MultiExpDecays = []
    model = Model(MultiExpDecay, independent_vars=['tiempo'])
    for c in range(len(V_APD.columns)):
        xdat = tiempo.iloc[:, c]
        ydat = V_APD.iloc[:, c]
        pars = model.guess(ydat, x=xdat)
        fit = model.fit(ydat, pars, x=xdat)
        fit_values = model.eval(pars, x=xdat)
        Fit_MultiExpDecays.append(fit_values)
        for key in fit.params:
            if key == 'C1':
                #print(key, "=", out.params[key].value, "+/-", out.params[key].stderr)
                C1s.append(fit.params[key].value)
                C1s_error.append(fit.params[key].stderr)
            elif key == 'C2':
                C2s.append(fit.params[key].value)
                C2s_error.append(fit.params[key].stderr)
            elif key == 'tau1':
                tau1s.append(fit.params[key].value)
                tau1s_error.append(fit.params[key].stderr)
            elif key == 'tau2':
                tau2s.append(fit.params[key].value)
                tau2s_error.append(fit.params[key].stderr)
    Fit_MultiExpDecays = np.transpose(pd.DataFrame(Fit_MultiExpDecays, index=labels))
    C1 = np.transpose(pd.DataFrame(C1s, index = labels, columns = ['C1']))
    C2 = np.transpose(pd.DataFrame(C2s, index=labels, columns=['C2']))
    tau1 = np.transpose(pd.DataFrame(tau1s, index=labels, columns=['tau1']))
    tau2 = np.transpose(pd.DataFrame(tau2s, index=labels, columns=['tau2']))
    C1_error = np.transpose(pd.DataFrame(C1s_error, index = labels, columns=['C1 error']))
    C2_error = np.transpose(pd.DataFrame(C2s_error, index=labels, columns=['C2 error']))
    tau1_error = np.transpose(pd.DataFrame(tau1s_error, index=labels, columns=['tau1 error']))
    tau2_error = np.transpose(pd.DataFrame(tau2s_error, index=labels, columns=['tau2 error']))
    C1 = pd.concat([C1, C1_error])
    C2 = pd.concat([C2, C2_error])
    tau1 = pd.concat([tau1, tau1_error])
    tau2 = pd.concat([tau2, tau2_error])
    return C1, C2, tau1, tau2, Fit_MultiExpDecays

C1, C2, tau1, tau2, Fit_MultiExpDecays = MultiExpDEcay_fit():
```

An error is raised but cannot identify the problem.

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py", line 737, in guess
    raise NotImplementedError(msg)
NotImplementedError: guess() not implemented for Model
```

Comment: Does the [standard example for fitting your own function](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html) not do the trick? Can you explain in more detail what would be different in your case? Cheers

Comment: Thanks for you answer @mikuszefski .

The Built-in ExponentialModel has to parameters: A (amplitude) and Tau (decay). it works with the initial guess parameters "pars = model.guess(ydat, x=xdat)". However, I want to fit my data to a biexponential Model (who is not a built-in function), with parameters C1 and C2 as amplitudes, and ta1 and tau2 as decays constants.

In the same line of codes it says to me: "Assigning result of a fucntion call, where the function has no return"

Comment: Yes, I got that. The example in the link actually is for a Gaussian, but the point is that this is a placeholder for an arbitrary function and I do not see why it should not work for a double exponential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use two `lmfit.ExponentialModel`, as with

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit.models import ExponentialModel

def dblexp( x, c1, l1, c2, l2 ):
    return c1 * np.exp( -x / l1 ) + c2 * np.exp( -x / l2 )
    
xl = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
yl = dblexp(xl, 32.44, 0.81, 11.51, 9.22 ) + np.random.normal(0, 0.2, xl.size)

mymodel = ExponentialModel(prefix='e1_') + ExponentialModel(prefix='e2_') 

params = mymodel.make_params(e1_amplitude=10, e1_decay=10,
                             e2_amplitude=25, e2_decay=0.50)

result = mymodel.fit(yl, params, x=xl)
print( result.fit_report() )
```

For the actual question:  As the exception says, `Model` does not know how to guess reasonable parameter values for an arbitrary, user-defined model function - the `Model.guess()` method raises this exception by default and must be overwritten by each subclass.  `lmfit` provides this method for the provided submodels (including `ExponentialModel`), but these are each coded with an understanding of those particular models.

Finally: fitting double-exponential decay is notoriously error-prone and difficult for least-squares approaches (or at least Levenberg-Marquardt implementations). For more realistic cases, I would recommend fitting the log of the data with the log of the double-exponential decay.

Answer (score 1):

`lmfit` is designed such that you do not have to do all the programming you have done here. it should just look like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import linspace
from numpy import fromiter
from numpy import exp
from numpy.random import normal
from lmfit import Model


def dblexp( x, c1, l1, c2, l2 ):
    return c1 * exp( -x / l1 ) + c2 * exp( -x / l2 )
    
xl = linspace(0, 10, 101)
yl = dblexp( xl, 32.44, 0.81, 11.51, 9.22 ) + normal(0, 0.2, xl.size)


mymodel = Model( dblexp ) 

### need some good guesses to start with
params = mymodel.make_params(c1=30, l1=1, c2=5, l2 =10)

result = mymodel.fit(yl, params, x=xl)
print( result.fit_report() )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.scatter( xl, yl )
ax.plot( xl, result.best_fit, 'r-' )
plt.show()
```

Providing:

```py
[[Model]]
    Model(dblexp)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 26
    # data points      = 101
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 4.77426620
    reduced chi-square = 0.04921924
    Akaike info crit   = -300.239903
    Bayesian info crit = -289.779421
[[Variables]]
    c1:  32.5481660 +/- 0.18540661 (0.57%) (init = 30)
    l1:  0.79183180 +/- 0.00931390 (1.18%) (init = 1)
    c2:  11.6241194 +/- 0.16669056 (1.43%) (init = 5)
    l2:  9.11790608 +/- 0.19623957 (2.15%) (init = 10)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(c2, l2) = -0.949
    C(l1, c2) = -0.822
    C(l1, l2) =  0.733
    C(c1, c2) = -0.652
    C(c1, l2) =  0.645
    C(c1, l1) =  0.251
```

and

[image: Test fit]